# How to link uploaded-file from a form to a model with Flask?

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently working on a very basic ecommerce platform for learning purposes. And I've stumbled across some difficulties which I couldn't find any book or resources that answers it. However, I am sure there should be an easier solution that I didn't recognise...

The aim is to upload a file along with the other form data to the database, so that the file is linked to that product id. Below is an example,

```
class ProductForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Design', validators=[Required()])
    series = SelectField('Collection', choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Series.query.all()], coerce=int)
    material = SelectField('Material', choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Material.query.all()], coerce=int)
    purity = SelectField('Purity', choices=[(c.id, c.name) for c in Purity.query.all()], default=['1'], coerce=int)
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[Required()])
    price = IntegerField('Price', validators=[Required()])
    photo = Filefield('Gallery')
    submit = SubmitField('Add to Display')
```

I know that the photo should be stored in some folder rather than within the database, the problem is that I have no idea how to refer the photo's location within the database, Below is the DB for the product,

```
class Artwork(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artworks'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    series_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('series.id'), default='1')
    material_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('materials.id'))
    purity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('purities.id'))
    description = db.Column(db.String)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    photo = db.Column(??)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Also, below is the product part of my view.py

```
@main.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin():
    form = ProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        artwork = Artwork(name=form.name.data, series_id = form.series.data, material_id = form.material.data, purity_id = form.purity.data, description = form.description.data, price = form.price.data)
        db.session.add(artwork)
        filename = secure_filename(form.uploads.data.filename)
        form.uploads.data.save('app/upload/' + filename)
        flash('The design have been posted.')
    else:
        filename = None
    return render_template('admin.html', form=form, filename=filename)
```

Anyone care to weigh in on this? It would make my day.

Comment: `photo = db.Column(db.String(100))` store the filename of the uploaded `photo`

Comment: do you want to save the file in database or in a directory in the server and link it in the database?

Comment: Hi @salmanwahed, Thanks for your reply, I want to save the file in a directory, for example app/upload/, but I am unsure of how exactly this works.

Comment: Hi @Navaneethan, thanks for you reply. I am still kind of in the cloud, say I did photo = db.Column(db.String(100)), what are the required code in the form.py for me to link the form submission to record this data in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `form` where you are posting the data you have to give the `enctype=multipart/form-data` like,

`<form action="/admin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

In your application you have to give the path of the upload directory,

`UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads/'`

And specify it in application's `config` in your case,

`main.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER`

Check the  [Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/).

You can give the name of the file a uniquely generated name and insert the `filename` as a column in a row in the database. or you can name it by the `id` of the `row` you are inserting. That way you can find your file for a item. I used first method in my case and generated unique `filename` using [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).